# Troubleshooting Window Builder Issues in Eclipse: It's Not Working

Tags: eclipse, swing, windowbuilder, swingbuilder

When I try to add and then try to edit, it can't be. I have uninstalled and installed several times but it dosen't works.

[image]

I have installed latest version all of it.

Comment: Please tell the exact versions of the WindowBuilder plugin and of the Eclipse you have and also of the Java with which you run Eclipse and of the Java you use in your project (latest version is not a proper version number and depends on when and from where you installed it; same for latest release which you probably mean). Please show your code (click on the _Source_ tab in the lower left corner) and tell what value you tried to edit [so your issue can be reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).